# Share a button with multiple pages in a Tab Control in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

Is there a way to share a button with multiple pages in a C# Windows Forms Application; so that the button will be available in two or more pages?

I tried:

```
this.Page1.Controls.Add(this.Button1);
this.Page2.Controls.Add(this.Button1);
```

But it does not work for me and the button `Button1` is still available only in `Page1`.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? You can instead of sharing the button itself, share the event handlers

Comment: No you cannot share it, each control belongs to a single parent and cannot be present in multiple parent's control collection. Put it over the tab control (not inside the pages) or use different buttons in each tab page but share the same event handler or in tab selection change, move it to another tab page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot share it, each control belongs to a single parent and cannot be shared between multiple parents. You can use either of the following options:

- Use a single button but in tab selection change, move it to another tab page:

  ```
  private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Will be removed from previous tab and added to new selected tab
      tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(button1);
  }
  ```
- Use different buttons in each tab page but share the same event handler

  ```
  button1.Click += button_Click;
  button2.Click += button_Click;
  ...
  private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //var clicked = (Button)sender;
      //Do somthing
  }
  ```
- Put it over the tab control, not inside the pages (pay attention to document outline):

  [image]